# Doctrine2 MongoDB ODM Compound Key (UniqueEntity)

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I'm having trouble implementing something in Zf2 and Doctrine2 using MongoDB that's fairly straightforward in Symfony2 and Doctrine2.

I have an Invoice Document where I want to make sure the combination of the Invoice::pattern and Invoice::number is unique. A number can appear multiple times, same as the pattern but the combination of the pattern and invoice number should be unique.

In **Symfony2** I would use the bridge

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

@UniqueEntity({"pattern", "number"})
class Invoice
{
...
```

But this doesn't work in Zf2 for obvious reasons.

My current annotation setup in **Zend Framework 2** is

```
/**
 * Class Invoice
 * @package Common\Document\Billing
 *
 * @ODM\Document(
 *     collection="invoice"
 * )
 * @ODM\UniqueIndex(keys={"prefix"="asc", "number"="asc"})
 * @ODM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_IMPLICIT")
 */
class Invoice
{
...
```

But this does actually allow an invoice being persisted with the same pattern and number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're comparing apples with pears here.

#### Doctrine MongoDB ODM

The `@ODM\UniqueIndex` index is part of [Doctrine MongoDB ODM](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's purpose is to create/update an index when running the console commands `odm:schema:create` / `odm:schema:update`. MongoDB uses those indexes to speed up lookups.

When creating a unique index, MongoDB will enforce that uniqueness. You can see this as a sort of validation on a database level.

Because this all is part of Doctrine MongoDB ODM and MongoDB itself, you can use it in whatever framework you want. Symfony 2 or Zend Framework 2 doesn't make a difference here.

#### User input validation

The `@UniqueEntity` annotation is part of [Symfony 2's Validator Component](http://symfony.com/components/Validator). This component can be used on its own, but most developers use the [Form Component](http://symfony.com/components/Form), which in turn uses the Validator component for form validation. Its purpose is to validate user input.

In other words: This kind of validation is completely different from what MongoDB does. While the Validator component enforces rules when user input is received (thus *before* data is sent to a database), MongoDB enforces data integrity while it tries to store it (thus *after* data is sent to the database).

#### Equivalent in ZF2

I think you're searching for an equivalent of the `@UniqueEntity` annotation in Zend Framework 2. You'll need to look towards the [ZF2 Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.validator.html), or at least the [ZF2 Validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.intro.html).

You're probably using the [ZF2 DoctrineModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule), or at least the the [ZF2 DoctrineMongoODMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule). Have a look at the [validator documentation of ZF2 DoctrineModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md) to see how to use this.

Comment: The problem with @ODM\UniqueIndex in DoctrineMongoDB is that the insert fails silently and doesn't throw an exception. The $dm->flush(["safe" => true]); has been deprecated so currently I'm stuck handling a failed insert.

Comment: The constraint is a database level thing. I don't have any experience with Doctrine Mongo ODM, so I'll believe you when you say that the persistence failure doesn't bubble up to the ODM. __But__ the point I'm trying to make is that you're comparing apples (framework-level validation) with pears (db-level constraints). If you want something like SF2's `@UniqueEntity` behavior in ZF2 you're going to need a ZF2 Validator (like the one in DoctrineModule).